# find . -name "documentation.html" | xargs xdg-open

Tags: bash, xdg

The (bash) command `find . -name "documentation.html" | xargs xdg-open`
 finds a file and passes its path to xdg-open, but xdg-open errors out:

```
xdg-open: unexpected argument './distribution/docs/target/docs/html/documentation.html'
```

The command `find . -name "documentation.html" -exec xdg-open {} +` results in the same error

Why? Is `find` passing the quote character to xdg-open? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by extra characters piped into xargs or errors (i.e. permission denied for certain dirs).

If you want to pass only one file to xargs you can try this:

```
find -type f -name "documentation.html" 2> /dev/null | head -n 1 | xargs -n 1 xdg-open
```

or

```
xdg-open `find -type f -name "examples.desktop" 2> /dev/null`
```

Another solution will be while loop:

```
find -type f -name "examples.desktop" 2> /dev/null | while read -r FILE ; do xdg-open "$FILE" ; done
```

Comment: So xdg-open is interpreting the argument as a .... list?

Comment: yes, read about it here: https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs

Comment: Oddly "find . -name "documentation.html" | xargs xdg-open" just starting doing what I would expect it to do -- open the file "documentation.html" in a web browser. I have no idea why it suddenly started working.